# Ruby - Can I Move This Logic To a Global Variable?

Tags: ruby, iteration, global-variables, continue

In an instance, in a method, I loop through a list `lines` and manipulate each `line`.  However, there are some `lines` which I want to skip.  I'd like to define which `lines` to skip with some global variables at the top of the instance.  Is that possible? How can I do that?

```
class Bets

  #stuff

  def make_prediction 
    lines.each do |line|
      next if @league == :nba && line[:bet_type] == :total && line[:period] == :h1
      next if [:total, :spread, :money_line].include?(line[:bet_type]) && line[:period] == :fg
      #do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:

someone voted for this topic to be closed as unhelpful cause it's unclear.  I'm not sure what is unclear about it.  But I'll make it more explicit how I want it to look...

```
class Bets
  #psuedo code, obviously this wont work
  #and i cant think how to make it work
  #or if its even possible
  GLOBAL = true if @league == :nba & line[:bet_type] == :total & line[:period] == :h1 

  #stuff

  def make_prediction 
    lines.each do |line|
      next if GLOBAL #psuedo code
      #do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Avoid using global variables, in most cases they would hurt you, different object instances can alter their state

Comment: What is the logic behind skipping a line? Do you want to do an exact match on the lines that should be ignored? Or do they match a certain regex pattern? Maybe something more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

What about using methods:

```
class Bets

  def skip?  
    @league == :nba & line[:bet_type] == :total & line[:period] == :h1 
  end
  #stuff

  def make_prediction 
    lines.each do |line|
      next if skip?          
      #do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Global variables are largely frowned upon, so try to find a context where your test make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Proc and executing it in the instance's context

```
GLOBAL = Proc.new {|line| your_code_goes_here}
#...
#...
def make_prediction 
  lines.each do |line|
    next if instance_exec(line,GLOBAL) #psuedo code
    #do stuff
  end
end
```